# PyQt5 - Show QDialog from a different class

Tags: qt, python-3.x, pyqt5, qdialog

My app consist of a `QMainWindow` with a `QToolBar`. My purpose is to click on a `QToolBar` element and open in a separate window (`QDialog`) a calendar.

I want to create in a separate class a `QDialog` and call it to be shown from the `QMainWindow`.

This is my `QDialog`, just a Calendar:

```
class CalendarDialog(QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(self)
        cal = QCalendarWidget(self)
```

Now from a `QMainWindow` I would like to show the calendar after an action trigger like next:

```
class Example(QMainWindow):
    ...
    calendarAction.triggered.connect(self.openCalendar)
    ...
    def openCalendar(self):
        self.calendarWidget = CalendarDialog(self)
        self.calendarWidget.show()
```

It isn't working. After the event that calls `openCalendar` the app is closed without printing any output error. I have put some prints to debug and `CalendarDialog.__init__(self)` isn't even called.

The code regarding to `QToolBar` is as follow:

```
openCalendarAction = QAction(QIcon(IMG_CALENDAR), "", self)
openCalendarAction.triggered.connect(self.openCalendar)
self.toolbar.addAction(openCalendarAction)
```

Comment: You're not creating a `CalendarDialog` in this line `self.calendarWidget = SMCalendarWidget(self)`, does `SMCalendarWidget` even exists?

Comment: yep, you are right. It was a transcription mistake. I have corrected the code.

Comment: Ok, can you share the code when you "create" the `toolBar`? The provided seems almost correct, except that `CalendarDialog.__init__(self)` take no arguments (self is implicit) and you are calling it `CalendarDialog(self)` with an argument, probably you want to specify a `parent` argument in the `__init__`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The posted code seems almost correct, here a complete working example, I've added some `resize` to make the widget size "acceptable":

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class CalendarDialog(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.cal = QCalendarWidget(self)

        self.resize(300, 300)
        self.cal.resize(300, 300)

class Example(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(400, 200)

        toolBar = QToolBar(self)

        calendarAction = QAction(QIcon('test.png'), 'Calendar', self)
        calendarAction.triggered.connect(self.openCalendar)
        toolBar.addAction(calendarAction)

    def openCalendar(self):
        self.calendarWidget = CalendarDialog(self)
        self.calendarWidget.show()


app = QApplication([])

ex = Example()
ex.show()

app.exec_()
```

Comment: Your solution works perfect :D Thanks!! Now I am trying to move `class CalendarDialog` to a different .py file, and it does not work... do you have an idea why??

Comment: Any Error? Are you executing the right file (the one with `app.exec_()`)?

Comment: The thing is that no errors are shown in the outline... the app just closes... I am thinking about my imports... I have created a new package `main.widgets` and here I have located the `CalendarDialog.py`. To import it: `from main.widgets import CalendarDialog` is right?

Comment: That way you're importing the `CalendarDialog` module, then to use the class you should use `CalendarDialog.CalendarDialog`, otherwise to import the class directly use `from main.widgets.CalendarDialog import CalendarDialog`, for distinguish those better I suggest you to use lowercase names for the files/modules (with underscore `_` if needed).

Comment: Ok, it is working right! Thanks. So, what is the convention regarding to .py files naming? lowercase with underscore?

Comment: Done! Thank you :D