# pyqt5 send/show messages from different file/class

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have two files, "main.py", "debugger.py".

On "debugger.py" I have a "textEdit" where I want to get/show messages.

On "main.py" I import and instantiate the class from "debugger.py" but instead of just sending/showing the messages, it opens the "debugger.py" window UI and shows the messages, i just need to send the message without opening the window, how can I do that?

"debugger.py".

```
import os, time
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QTextCursor


class Debugger_MainWindow(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    #def print_text(self):
        #self.txtEdit_debugger.insertPlainText('hi')

    def Debugger_setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.lbl_info = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.lbl_info.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 450, 451, 61))
        self.lbl_info.setObjectName("lbl_info")

        self.lbl_tittle = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.lbl_tittle.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 40, 56, 15))
        self.lbl_tittle.setObjectName("lbl_tittle")

        self.txtEdit_debugger = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        #self.txtEdit_debugger.setEnabled(False)
        self.txtEdit_debugger.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 80, 481, 361))
        self.txtEdit_debugger.setObjectName("txtEdit_debugger")
        self.txtEdit_debugger.setReadOnly(True)

        ##Check box on/off
        self.chkb_on_off_debugger = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.chkb_on_off_debugger.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 500, 30, 20))  
        self.chkb_on_off_debugger.setObjectName("chkb_on_off_debugger")
        #self.chkb_on_off_debugger.stateChanged.connect(self.print_text)#Show logger messages
        self.chkb_on_off_debugger.setCheckable(True)
        

        self.lbl_on_off_debugger = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.lbl_on_off_debugger.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 500, 60, 20))
        self.lbl_on_off_debugger.setObjectName("lbl_on_off_debugger")
        
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.lbl_info.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "This is read only mode. "))
        self.lbl_tittle.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Debugger"))
        self.lbl_on_off_debugger.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Show messages"))
        self.lbl_on_off_debugger.adjustSize()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Debugger_MainWindow()
    ui.Debugger_setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

"main.py"

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot, QThreadPool, QTimer 
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor, QKeySequence, QIcon, QTextCursor
from Debugger import Debugger_MainWindow


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    
    ###### Methods

    #this method opens a new window, i just want to send the message
    def print_text(self):
        self.ui_debugger = Debugger_MainWindow()
        self.ui_debugger.Debugger_setupUi(MainWindow)
        self.ui_debugger.txtEdit_debugger.insertPlainText('hi')

   
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(500, 500)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet(open("styles.qss", "r").read())
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
         
        ##Group box
        self.gpb_spell_main = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.gpb_spell_main.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 5, 290, 230))
        self.gpb_spell_main.setObjectName("gpb_spell_main")
        self.gpb_spell_main.setCheckable(True)
        self.gpb_spell_main.setChecked(False)           

        ##Button
        spell_main_color = QColor(255, 0, 255)
        self.btn_spell_main = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gpb_spell_main)
        self.btn_spell_main.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 35, 85, 27))
        self.btn_spell_main.setObjectName("btn_spell_main")
        self.btn_spell_main.clicked.connect(self.print_text)
        #self.btn_spell_main.setEnabled(False)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        
    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.gpb_spell_main.setTitle(_translate("HeallingWindow", "Spell Main"))
        self.btn_spell_main.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Click Here"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)    
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Note: I couldn't fix my issue reading similar questions. [PyQt5 - Show QDialog from a different class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38540711/pyqt5-show-qdialog-from-a-different-class)

Comment: it would be simpler to copy message code from one class to another.

Comment: if you don't want to see Debug window then DON'T run `self.ui_debugger.Debugger_setupUi(MainWindow)` . But when window doesn't exist then doesn't exist also `textEdit` - so you can't get/set value in this widget. Eventually you can hide existing window.

Comment: @furas, How eventually I can hide the existing window?, All the content is going to be on main.py, my other window is going to be called just to check the messages if needed.
self.ui_debugger.hide(MainWindow) don't do the trick.

Comment: rather `self.ui_debugger.hide()` without parameters - similar to `.show()` which also is without parameters.

Comment: @furas, I get this error "AttributeError: 'Debugger_MainWindow' object has no attribute 'hide'" when I use "self.ui_debugger.hide()". Is there a way to just send/show the message on other window?, what you mean with "simpler to copy message code from one class to another", do you have a short example?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do - if you don't want to display Debug Window then its `textEdit` is useless for you - because you can't see it. And if you want to run `debugger.py` as separated program then it also useless because separated programs can't share variable. Pograms would have to use some queue or socket or file to send value from one program to another.

Comment: @furas sorry, let me try again, from main.py I just want to send messages, all those messages are going to be displayed on debugger.py. Based on your comments it seems that the best way to do it is creating a file with all the classes and just pass from one to the other, because the way that am doing it looks like two different programs, right?

Comment: I don't understand this: you want to display on debugger.py but you don't want to display Debuger Window - so how you want to display it without window ?

Comment: or maybe you runs `python debugger.py` and later `python main.py` and you want send message from program `python main.py` to program `python debugger.py`? But you can't import code from file `debugger.py` to file`main.py` to have access to `python debugger.py`. It will create new window debuger without access to previous window. it would need to use queue, file or socket to send something from one running program to another program.

Comment: @furas, it is just the same program ... lets say that i have 3 buttons on main.py and I clicked each one, every time that I clicked one a "print("clicked button")" statement is showed on console, right? ... instead of the console I want those 3 prints to be displayed on my debug window when am done clicking, kind of accessing to your logs from an UI.

Comment: so what is the problem to create instance of Debug Window and put text in this window. And if you want reuse it then create it in `__init__` instead of `print_text()` - this way you will create it only once - instead of create it again and again when you run `print_text()`.

Comment: Eventually in `__init__` create `self.ui_debugger = None` and later in `print_text()` check `if self.ui_debugger is None: self.ui_debugger = Debugger_MainWindow()` - this way you also create it only once. And if you want to close this window then set again `self.ui_debugger = None` so it will create new window when you run again `print_text()`

Comment: @furas, when I created an instance of debug window and put the text, didn't work.
self.ui_debugger = Debugger_MainWindow()
self.ui_debugger.txtEdit_debugger.insertPlainText('hi')

Can u share a clear example tho?, thanks

Comment: what meas `didn't work`? I can't see your computer, and I can't read in your mind?

Comment: for Debuger Window you may have to create new `QtWidgets.QMainWindow()`  - if you use existing  `MainWindow` then you replace widgets in existing window.

Comment: @furas, sorry my last comment was written before yours, so ...

In my __init__ i tired to instantiate debuger like this "self.ui_debugger = Debugger_MainWindow()", then I put this on my print_text method "    def print_text(self):        
        if self.ui_debugger is None:
            "self.ui_debugger.txtEdit_debugger.insertPlainText('hi')". it is not doing anything, if I put self.ui_debugger.txtEdit_debugger.insertPlainText('hi')" without  if self.ui_debugger is None: it shows this error "AttributeError: 'Debugger_MainWindow' object has no attribute 'txtEdit_debugger".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I understand problem but you may have to create new `QtWidgets.QMainWindow()` to create separated Debug Window. If you use existing `MainWindow` then it replaces widgets in existing window.

You may also set `None` to Debug Window in `__init__` and later check if Debug Window is not None - to create only one window.

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.DebugWindow = None

    def print_text(self):
        if self.DebugWindow is None:
            self.DebugWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
            self.ui_debugger = Debugger_MainWindow()
            self.ui_debugger.Debugger_setupUi(self.DebugWindow)

        self.DebugWindow.show()
        self.ui_debugger.txtEdit_debugger.insertPlainText('hi\n')
```

---

Other problem cam be when you close Debug Window because it will not opne it again. It may need to change code in Debug Window and assign function which will hide it instead of destroing it.

Comment: it is working now, it is printing the messages. It was hard to explain but thank you for your help!